# using Interface to express object in Typescript types declaration

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm writing types declaration for a framework, for a function, it has a parameter whose type is `object`, but I want to describe it using `interface` in the declaration type like this:

```
interface Options{
    template: string | Selector | AST;
    config (data: object): void;
}

interface Regular_Static {
    new (options: Options): Regular_Instance;
    // todo
}
declare var Regular: Regular_Static;

export = Regular
```

But when I write like this in my application:

```
class HelloRegular extends Regular {
    constructor(options: object){
        super(options);
    }
}
```

it shows that `type object can't be assignment to type Options`. So how to do with it?

supplement: The `Options` type declaration can't be got in application unless we declare it in our application. I mean to let the `Options` do like an object.

Comment: If the constructor for `Regular_Static` expects an object with `template` and `config` why would the compiler allow you to call the constructor (as `super(options)`) with an object that may not have those properties ?

Comment: So what happens when you change `options: object` to `options: Options`?

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir There is no type `Options` in application

Comment: @laoqiren you define the type in the declarations, it's an interface, it does not need an implementation, so you can use it, as people have done in the answers :)

Answer (score 1):

Take the proper type here:

```
interface Options{
  template: string | Selector | AST;
  config (data: object): void;
}

class HelloRegular extends Regular {
  constructor(options: Options){
    super(options);
  }
}
```

Comment: But the `Options` type declaration is not in the application and it is only at the declaration type file.

Comment: @laoqiren no problem as ts got duck typing.

Answer (score 0):

you can import that interface to you class like that

```
      export interface Options{
             template: string | Selector | AST;
             config (data: object): void;
    }

      export interface Regular_Static {
           new (options: Options): Regular_Instance;
        // todo
                 }
```

and here import that interface and class to use it

```
    import { Options, Regular_Static} from 'yourfile.ts';
    class HelloRegular extends Regular {
          constructor(options: Options){
           super(options);
            }
        }
```